# How to generate a Buchi Automaton from a LTL formula?

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin, automaton, formal-methods

How can I generate a Buchi Automaton starting from an LTL formula?

**e.g.**

```
[] (a <-> ! b)
```

That is,

> At all times in the future
>
> - if `a` is true `b` is false
> - if `b` is true `a` is false

Comment: [This Q/A is meant to replace this self-deleted question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597401/creation-of-buchi-automaton-from-statement/61602307)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [**gltl2ba**](https://github.com/PatrickTrentin88/gltl2ba), which is based on [**ltl2ba**](http://www.lsv.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php).

> **LTL Formulas**
>
> An LTL formula may contain propositional symbols, boolean operators,
>   temporal operators, and parentheses.
>
> - Propositonal Symbols:
>
>   ```
>   true, false
>   any lowercase string
>   ```
> - Boolean operators:
>
>   ```
>   !   (negation)
>   ->  (implication)
>   <-> (equivalence)
>   &&  (and)
>   ||  (or)
>   ```
> - Temporal operators:
>
>   ```
>    G   (always) (Spin syntax : [])
>    F   (eventually) (Spin syntax : <>)
>    U   (until)
>    R   (realease) (Spin syntax : V)
>    X   (next)
>   ```
>
> Use spaces between any symbols.
>
> *(source: [ltl2ba webpage](http://www.lsv.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php))*

---

**Example:** generate a Buchi Automaton from the next LTL formula:

```
[](a <-> ! b)
```

This reads: *it is always true that `a` if and only if `!b` (and viceversa)*. That is, this is the formula you want to encode.

The following command generates the never claim associated with the LTL formula, and also the Buchi Automaton (option `-g`).

```
~$ ./gltl2ba -f "[](a <-> ! b)" -g
never { /* [](a <-> ! b) */
accept_init:
    if
    :: (!b && a) || (b && !a) -> goto accept_init
    fi;
}
```

[image]

---

More examples are available [here](https://github.com/PatrickTrentin88/gltl2ba).